# Is it possible to attach a file to a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, rmarkdown, attachfile

I am familiar with the navigator package, which works flawlessly in long documents. However, I recently wanted to attach a file to a beamer presentation.

I am not using LaTex, but rmarkdown to create the beamer presentations using the `beamer_presentation` output option and `xelatex` as render option. The use of navigator seems not to work, when adding the header-includes:

```
 \usepackage{navigator}
 \embeddedfile{2020-reuniao}{2020-reuniao.Rmd}
```

No error or warning is given, the resulting file does not have an embedded `2020-reuniao.Rmd` file.

- How can I have an embedded file in a beamer presentation using rmarkdown?

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-solus-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Solus 4.1 Fortitude

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/haswell/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.9.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.0         stringr_1.4.0         dplyr_1.0.2          
 [4] purrr_0.3.4           readr_1.4.0           tidyr_1.1.2          
 [7] tibble_3.0.4          tidyverse_1.3.0       ggplot2_3.3.2        
[10] naniar_0.6.0          visdat_0.5.3          here_0.1             
[13] summarytools_0.9.6    ProjectTemplate_0.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5         lubridate_1.7.9    assertthat_0.2.1   rprojroot_1.3-2   
 [5] digest_0.6.27      R6_2.5.0           cellranger_1.1.0   plyr_1.8.6        
 [9] backports_1.2.0    reprex_0.3.0       evaluate_0.14      httr_1.4.2        
[13] pillar_1.4.6       rlang_0.4.8        readxl_1.3.1       rstudioapi_0.11   
[17] magick_2.5.2       checkmate_2.0.0    rmarkdown_2.5      labeling_0.4.2    
[21] pander_0.6.3       munsell_0.5.0      broom_0.7.2        compiler_3.6.3    
[25] modelr_0.1.8       xfun_0.19          pkgconfig_2.0.3    base64enc_0.1-3   
[29] htmltools_0.5.0    tcltk_3.6.3        tidyselect_1.1.0   codetools_0.2-16  
[33] matrixStats_0.57.0 fansi_0.4.1        crayon_1.3.4       dbplyr_2.0.0      
[37] withr_2.3.0        grid_3.6.3         jsonlite_1.7.1     gtable_0.3.0      
[41] lifecycle_0.2.0    DBI_1.1.0          magrittr_1.5       scales_1.1.1      
[45] cli_2.1.0          stringi_1.5.3      farver_2.0.3       pryr_0.1.4        
[49] fs_1.5.0           xml2_1.3.2         ellipsis_0.3.1     rapportools_1.0   
[53] generics_0.1.0     vctrs_0.3.4        tools_3.6.3        glue_1.4.2        
[57] hms_0.5.3          yaml_2.2.1         colorspace_1.4-1   rvest_0.3.6       
[61] knitr_1.30         haven_2.3.1
```

Comment: both attachfile2 and navigator worked fine for me in a small example. "This doesn't work" is not a sufficient problem description.